# My wallpaper isn't changing in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, desktop-background

I'm new to linux OS.

I tried changing my wallpaper using `right click>change desktop background`
but there are no changes after selecting any wallpaper,it's the same orange background!
please tell me solution for it!

Comment: If you just right clicked and clicked "Change Desktop Background", you need to choose a background, it won't magically show you the background you wanted.

Comment: yes i did it but the wallpaper isn't changing.I tried my own wallpapers and also the wallpapers already available, but there are no changes!

Comment: Maybe some pictures will help.

Comment: check whether are you the admin ?

Comment: try your pictures to set as Wallpaper